# Is this a normal flight path to take?

Tags: airplane, flight-path

A few days ago I was flying from Munich to Chicago, the flight arrived about 20-25 minutes late, at some point, the pilot suddenly turned in completely the opposite direction as we were approaching Chicago, they then circled around, I was able to take this video (uploaded as a .gif)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUPRN.jpg

I had to miss my next flight due to the delayed arrival and the flight they then scheduled me on was delayed twice in that day. Now I'm asking out of curiosity about what would have caused the pilot to take such flight path.

**As for flight details**,
Flight No: Lufthansa 953
and Flight Time: July 7th, 11:55 am from Munich, Germany (MUC-Franz Josef Strauss Intl.) to Chicago, IL, United States (ORD-O'Hare
Intl.)

Comment: LH 953 is from Birmingham, UK to Frankfurt. Do you mean UA953, which is the code sharing Lufthansa flight?

Comment: @GdD This is what my itinerary has, I do believe that it is indeed UA953 on the United app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORD was busy & backed up pretty heavily on July 7 (I was there that day.) Plenty of inbound flights were holding, which is exactly what seems to be going on in that video. Not surprising that things ran late; too bad the connecting flight didn't run similarly late.

Comment: Yup. They did one racetrack pattern but the second was cut short into a 360.